# execute multi-line commands inside jenkins DSL plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins, dsl

**Using Jenkins 2**

Would like to generate dynamic choices from git repository. So, within groovySrcipt's script section,

```
job('example') {
parameters {
 activeChoiceParam('CHOICE-1') {
  description('Allows user choose from multiple choices')
  filterable()
  choiceType('SINGLE_SELECT')
  groovyScript {
   // script('["choice1", "choice2"]')
   script('-DYNANIC CHOICES-REF-PESUDO-CODE')
   fallbackScript('"fallback choice"')
  }
 }
}}
```

**Pseudo-code**

```
groovyScript {
 script('
   // call git repo and fetch some branches info.
   // collect them in some local variable and return them as choices
   def branches = "git branch -l"
   return branches 
 ')
 fallbackScript('"fallback choice"')
}
```

In my case, it is always going to fallback script.
Please share your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins job or pipeline input are displayed before job really start.
I faced same requirement and ended with a job that update it's own parameter setup and ask for re-run.

ie :

- Check job setup is ok

  - if not ok, create it and update job status with "CANCEL" and provide user a message or description to
  - job is ok, meaning parameter were already provided by user at this stage

**EDIT**

Sample code :

```
EXPECTED_VERSION = "v1.1"

// check setup : read variable "SETUP_VERSION" and compare with constant in code
if ( "${SETUP_VERSION}" != "${EXPECTED_VERSION}" ) {
  // if different, run setup and stop build
  createSetup()
  echo "Setup updated, please restar"
  currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
}
// else continue processing
...

// create setup
void createSetup() {

    def myParameters = [choice(
            choices: "${EXPECTED_VERSION}"
            , description: 'JenkinsFile version for internal testing only'
            , name: 'SETUP_VERSION'
    )]

   // stuff
   myParameters << string(
        defaultValue: ''
        , description: 'some input'
        , name: 'MY_INPUT')
}
```

Comment: Thannks Grunnpi for your comment on the post. Answer is still board for me. Can you please explain with some code snippet or reference documentation?

Comment: Updated answer with minimal code. You should adapt "flush setup" condition in order to compare current one with expected one _(I rely on version number)_